# Alarm is getting trigger even for past time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am setting one repetitive alarm which will get trigger at 9 pm everyday. So I am setting alarm immediately after login.  Here is my code.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, LogoutReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hourOfTheDay = new LocaleTranslation().getIntValue(KeysConstant.AUTO_LOGOUT_TIMER_VALUE, Constants.AUTO_LOGOUT_HOUR_OF_DAY_VALUE);
        int minutes = new LocaleTranslation().getIntValue(KeysConstant.AUTO_LOGOUT_TIMER_MINUTE_VALUE, Constants.AUTO_LOGOUT_MINUTE_VALUE);
        int seconds = new LocaleTranslation().getIntValue(KeysConstant.AUTO_LOGOUT_TIMER_SECOND_VALUE, Constants.AUTO_LOGOUT_SECOND_VALUE);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfTheDay );
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes );
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds );
        Objects.requireNonNull(alarmManager).setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        LMPSharedPrefs.getInstance().write(SharedPrefsConstants.PREFS_LOGOUT_SCHEDULER, TIMER_STARTED);
```

It's working fine and app is getting logout exactly at 9.01 pm. But If i login again, then again it's getting logout. Means my alarm is getting trigger for past time also.

Is there best approach to avoid triggering alarm for past time.

Comment: Try to check if the alarm you set is still up or not, if it is, then cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of this:**

```
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
```

**Add this:**

```
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfTheDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
```

You have initialized and declared your time values but you arent using them in your code.

Update:

```
   //region Enable Daily Notifications
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
      calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); //24 Hour.   
   Format - 10am alarm set.
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    // if notification time is before selected time, send. 
 notification the next day
    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    if (manager != null) {
     //your alarmanager repeating code here
    }
```

The calendar.before is the main logic here to compare the timings. If before doesnt works than try with after.

Comment: actually that's not an issues. It's still happening.